# Using pointers with classes in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I am familiar with creating classes and using dot notations to access functions for the objects. I am unfamiliar with the notation of doing the same but with pointers. Please take a look at my code and suggest how I change the code in the class definition, *not* main.

main:

```
Pet * p = new Pet( "Sunset", "Cat", "meow..." );

cout << "The " << p->getVariety( ) << " " << p->getName( ) << " speaks by saying " << p->spea( ) << endl;
```

class:

```
class Pet
{
public:
Pet( );
Pet( std::string name, std::string variety, std::string says )
{
    using namespace std;
    myName = name;
    myVariety = variety;
    howIspeak = says;
}

std::string getName( ) const
{
    return myName;
};
std::string getVariety( ) const
{
    return myVariety;
};

virtual void speak( );

protected:
std::string myName;
std::string myVariety;
std::string howIspeak;
};
```

Comment: Well, you will have to change `main` to add that missing semicolon. Anyway, your compiler should have some reasonable stuff to say about this with the warning level turned up (except considering mine doesn't, I think I'm hallucinating). Annnyway, your main issue stems from not using a constructor initializer list.

Comment: -invalid operands to binary expression...

Comment: What exactly an issue? What do we must suggest?

Answer (score 1):

I guess, it's the

```
virtual void speak( );
```

in

```
cout << "The " << "..." << p->speak( ) << endl;
```

which causes the error message. You cannot output a `void` value to `std::ostream`.

Presumably, it should have been

```
virtual std::string speak();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Please take a look at my code and suggest how I change the code in the class definition, not main.

The `using namespace std;` is useless in there, just remove it.

Then, you are having `virtual` methods and `protected` members, which suggests that you are willing to inherit from that class: either don't or define a `virtual` destructor as well.

Also, the `speak` member function you are calling from the main, returns `void`, which is not a type you want to pass to `operator<<` of `std::cout`.

And finally: why are you using *nake pointers* and dynamic allocation? Don't use it unless you are absolutely forced to, and even then, use `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` (or any other of the smart pointers family) instead:

```
std::unique_ptr<Pet> ptr(new Pet( "Sunset", "Cat", "meow..." ));
```

After that line, `ptr` will behave almost like any other pointer, except it will clean himself up (will call `delete`) when you are done with it (when it leaves the scope).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading an introductory book on C++, "C++ Primer (4th Edition)" by Lippmann et al. or finding an on-line tutorial on C++. The problem you are solving requires more understanding than can be related in an SO Q and A.